Publishing an article with only three citations on the arXiv
I wrote a paper about quantitative biology that is 55 pages long and has only three citations. Does this have a chance of being accepted on the arXiv?

Accepted where? on arXiv? Not sure what you are asking, citations are not something considered for accepting an article for publication

@Dr.Snoopy on arXiv. I saw a publication with 75 pages and 4 citations on arXiv.

We cannot predict if your paper will be accepted by arXiv or not, but length over 6-8 pages and number of citations are not part of the acceptance criteria. Why do you worry about citations?

Ok. I'm worry about the number of citations because this paper may be rejected due to low number of citations.

As I said that's not the acceptance criteria, it would not make sense, arXiv is a preprint server.

Do you mean the number of papers that your own paper is citing (as part of bibliography), or something else?

ArXiv contains course notes and other manuscripts not intended for later publication, and surely some of those have ZERO citations.

@Sulfura Arxiv is not a journal or conference. It's just a website where you can post papers so you can easily link to them. That's it. Anyone can post anything to Arxiv and it will "be accepted" provided it follows the basic guidelines.

Do you mean its been cited three times, or that you only reference three papers in the article? number of citations is generally the first.

@SpencerKraisler no, not anyone can post anything to arXiv and be accepted. That is the reason viXra was invented (not that I suggest submitting there). The work must satisfy scholarly standards, which would include citing the relevant literature. If by citations the OP means number of articles they cite, that likely doesn't reach scholarly standards.

I think you don't mean "citation" but "references". A citation is an occasion of someone else citing your paper.

As you already noticed, there are papers on the Arxiv which have a very low number of citations.
All such papers I have ever seen come from pure mathematics or adjacent fields.
These papers (and fields) cite so little, because they do not do introductions providing context embeddings.
They can get away with an introduction that is literally:
“We consider the problem of X.”
Quantitative biology is not such a field.
This is not just an arbitrary convention:
Arguably, if you disembed a work of quantitative biology from biological context, you are left with mathematical toying around.
For that reason, a reputable journal for quantitative biology is very unlikely to accept such a manuscript without substantial revisions.
Now, the Arxiv is not a journal and has lower standards for acceptance; so this is not a problem per se.
If an experienced quantitative biologist produced such a manuscript and just did not bother to write an introduction for whatever reason, it will likely meet the Arxiv’s criteria for publication.
But then, this rarely happens and if it does, the authors are completely aware of what they are doing.
The fact that you wrote such a manuscript strongly suggests that you are inexperienced with academic writing and do not have an experienced academic mentor.
(Further contributing to this suspicion is the rather high length of the manuscript and that you asked this question in the first place.)
All of this in turn makes it very unlikely that you produced academic writing meeting the Arxiv’s standards, and unfortunately the same applies to the research itself.
Now, at this point you might find that I guessed a lot here based on what information you provided and indeed I did.
But I am still confident in my conclusion as most of my guesses were already optimistic.
For example if you indeed wrote a substantial introduction, the low number of citations makes it almost certain that your writing doesn’t meet the Arxiv’s standards.

Nobody can predict if your paper will be accepted or not to arXiv (which is just a preprint server), because the acceptance criteria is just that your paper is really an academic research paper (and not some homework assignment or plain spam), and that it fits into one of the arXiv topics.
Citations is never considered for acceptance, because it would make no sense, many researchers post their papers in arXiv as a way to make them public, and papers need to be made public before they can get citations.

I think OP means that they only cited 3 other papers in their manuscript.

@BryanKrause Yes, could be, but its unclear from the question.
